# how to show only one record that you want from SQL data, is the best way to use select top 1?

Tags: sql, datetime, select, sql-order-by, sql-limit

This is my sql query,

```
select emailid,
       emailsentime


from [dbo].[clientbase]

where emailsent time > '1995-01-02'
and   emailsent time < '1995-01-03'

order by emailsenttime desc
```

But it's pulling all the emailids on that date, I only want to show the top row of record(because that is the most recent emailid sent on that date.

I want to experiment, since currently I'm doing by descending, if I'm doing ascending(which would be the least recent one).

But how do I get the top record only without pulling all the data.

what I  mean is one I ran this query, it shows data like this

```
emailid          emailsenttime

1986789          1995-01-02 22:51:12
1986788          1995-01-02 22:50:12
1986787          1995-01-02 22:49:12
1986786          1995-01-02 22:48:12
```

Comment: `select top 1 emailid, ...`

Comment: @jarlh, can you write an answer? I updated the query

Comment: Do you mean you want just one row to be returned, the most recent one?

Comment: @jarlh, yes the most recent is the top row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a row-limiting query.

In standard SQL, you would go:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
order by emailsenttime desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

That said, the syntax may vary depending on your database, for example:

- MySQL, Postgres:

  ```
  select ...
  from ...
  where ...
  order by emailsenttime desc
  limit 1
  ```
- Older versions of SQL Server:

  ```
  select top (1) ...
  from ...
  where ...
  order by emailsenttime desc
  ```